# turning off coverage in nosetests

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

How do I conditionally turn **off** coverage when running nosetests?

there is a --with-coverage flag that doesn't seem to do all that much.  It certainly does not turn off coverage.

Mind you, I like coverage and I want to keep it. I just find it extremely distracting to see its output every single time I run nosetests manually.  At that time, I want to see the test results and if anything failed.

My ~/.noserc has the following contents, but renaming the file did not help.

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=3
with-coverage=0
match=(?:^|[\b_\./-])[Tt]est|^ut_
cover-html=1
```

Most of the time, I would prefer to have the same nosetests behavior as if there was no coverage installed at all.

Last time I installed nose, I hacked together a --cover-none 1 option by modifying the optparse in the main launch script.  Basically, if the flag was set I would flip on the same "coverage is not installed" flag that the program uses to guard against coverage not being installed.  Worked fine, a bit kludgy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `with-coverage` option entirely from config file.

Long story: `--with-coverage`, like all other plugin turn-on flags is defined as `store-true` action ([in optparse context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#defining-options)), so any value, even 0, False or None will turn the plugin on. You have to remove the option entirely. When you remove `with-coverage,` default value of `False` will be used to turn the coverage plugin off.

Also, try running with `nosetests -v 3` to see what else could be messing with your setup.  Could you have `nose.cfg` sitting somewhere in your home directory?

Comment: Didn't work for me.  That's why I had renamed ~/.noserc to be something else, just in case it was something in the config file that was triggering it.  And I just type 'nosetests <ut script>' on the command line.  as to why it triggers on any value?... It probably depends how the optparse parameter handling code was written - sometimes any value is used to store True in a boolean.  Now, are you saying you have nose installed, as well as coverage, and you get no coverage report when you don't set --with-coverage?

Comment: Yes, setting it to 0 was not enough. Had to remove with-coverage from config file.

Comment: Looked at the code itself and it turns out you were right.  When I did 'export NOSE_IGNORE_CONFIG_FILES=1' my problems went away.  So I looked some more the configuration files.  Nose uses setup.cfg in the current directory as well as ~/.noserc.  I had looked for stray *nose* files in my test directory, but totally forgot about setup.cfg.  I've renamed it to nose_setup.cfg for now and will use the -c switch to explicitly use it as config file when running nose.